# Stain not drying

Tags: furniture

I have a kitchen table that I'm trying to refinish. I sanded it then applied Minwax stain. Well, apparently I didn't sand enough because now the stain is "tacky" after 3 days. I now know that it's just too cold for it to dry in a timely manner. My question is can I "strip" it off & start over? Maybe use a chalk paint or a water based stain? Any advice is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: How cold is it?

Comment: What is the humidity?

Comment: Can you go over it with a hair dryer?

Comment: Oil or water based?

Comment: Voting to close (OT > NEI). OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

If it is oil based, use a clean rag soaked in paint thinner and it will take the the sticky stuff off and allow it to dry the rest of the way.